# Method borrowing vs using call()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, call

I've started to learn about functions and this keyword. While learning about the call() and its usecase I found myself unclear of the below two scenarios which yields the same output
**Method Borrowing:**

```
const lufthansa = {
    airline: 'LUFT',
    iataCode: 500,
    bookings: [],
    book(name) {
        console.log(`${name} booked Airline: ${this.iataCode}-${this.airline}`)
        this.bookings.push({booking: `${name} booked Airline: ${this.iataCode}-${this.airline}`})
    }
}

const euroWings = {
    airline: 'EW',
    iataCode: 700,
    bookings: []
}

euroWings.book = lufthansa.book

lufthansa.book('John')
euroWings.book('Adam')
```

**Using Call()**

```
const lufthansa = {
    airline: 'LUFT',
    iataCode: 500,
    bookings: [],
    book(name) {
        console.log(`${name} booked Airline: ${this.iataCode}-${this.airline}`)
        this.bookings.push({booking: `${name} booked Airline: ${this.iataCode}-${this.airline}`})
    }
}

const euroWings = {
    airline: 'EW',
    iataCode: 700,
    bookings: []
}

lufthansa.book('John')
lufthansa.book.call(euroWings, 'Adam')
```

What are the real differences and when one should be used?

Comment: "*when one should be used?*" if you *don't* want the method on the other object, then use `.call()`. If you *do* want the method on the other object, transfer it over and call it.

Comment: When you're digging deeper to JS OOP, you'll find out, that methods are rarely defined as own properties of the objects, instead they're defined in a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), and the objects are created with a constructor, class or Object.create to include the methods in the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

`.call()` is generally used when you don't control the methods of the object, and want to use methods from some other object.

The classical example is using array methods on "array-like" objects that exist in the web interface, such as `NodeList`.

```
divs = document.getElementByClassName("myclass");
result = [].map.call(divs, function(div) { return div.getAttribute("someattr"); });
```

You *could* conceivably do

```
div.map = [].map;
result = div.map(function(div) { return div.getAttribute("someattr"); });
```

but borrowing the method every time would be repetitive.